# Does disabling Gatekeeper also disable code signing signature check?

Tags: macos, code-signing, gatekeeper

If I disable Gatekeeper on ML (I mean I allow apps from anywhere) is code signing disabled too or the Mac App Store will continue checking if apps are unmodified preventing from upgrading them if they don't pass the signature check?

Comment: I tried invalidating the code signatures of a few applications, and I could update them even if Gatekeeper was enabled. It might be something specific to my installation though.

Comment: Is it possible that code signing verification is not yet enabled in Mountain Lion?

Comment: I don't know. But some sandboxed applications like Mail and WriteRoom now seem to crash on launch if (some specific) resources have been modified.

Comment: I don't have WriteRoom but I (of course) have Mail, so: what resources did you modify?

Comment: Just an Info.plist. WriteRoom would crash if almost any file was modified. If [FoldingText](http://www.foldingtext.com) was modified, OS X showed a dialog about it being damaged and refused to open it, but that didn't happen with some other Developer ID applications. Anyway, I'm making a clean installation to test this.

Comment: Does disabling Gatekeeper allow you to run/update those apps without any issue?